# Mesh Smoothing leaving lines

Tags: mesh

I am getting these lines in my mesh when smoothing and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Surely it is something simple, but I am still fairly new to Blender. I have tried fixing normals as well as deleting and rebuilding these areas but still to no avail. I have no Ngons in my mesh to note. To be honest, I am not sure if this will even matter once this is unwrapped and painted textures/material is applied? Can someone point me in the right direction as I would really like to no what could be wrong and how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: hard to say how your topology looks like, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This is the result of the smooth shading algorithm interpolating across faces, between very different normals at their corners.  there are many ways to suppress the interpolation where you don't want it, depending on how your model is eventually going to be used.. search on 'smooth shading' here on BSE and elsewhere. In the mean time, a quick  fix would be to check 'Auto Smooth' in the object's Data tab > 'Normals' panel.